# Difficulty playing Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One online?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I tried to play the game online and while I could see a list of games available for play, I was unable to connect to any of them. After selecting a game to join I would see a loading screen for a time, then be told to re-request loading, which would always fail. What is going on? Is there some point in the game I need to progress to as a single player before multiplayer options are available to me?

Comment: you might just have a bad connection, the request reload is to give the option to the game leader to restart at the last activated checkpoint so you can join, if you get denied wait a few more minutes they might just passed a difficult part and don't wanna redo it or are near the next check point